# Simple basic Username and Password code for 1 user not working

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

I am VERY new to making websites and l am still very much learning. I have spent a huge amount of time today trying to figure out what is wrong in this piece of code I'm trying to use. Any help is much appreciated.

Main problem is that upon submit of incorrect or correct username/password, goes to blank page and not displaying incorrect username/password message. Thanks. Steve

**HTML**

```
<form id='login' action='login.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

        <label for='username' >UserName: </label>
        <input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName"  maxlength="50" required="true" />

        <label for='password' >Password:</label>
        <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" required="true"/>

        <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['username'])){ 

        if(($_POST['username'] == "admin") && ($_POST['password'] == "adminpass"))
        {
            $_SESSION['secured'] = "Secured";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Oops! Looks like the username and password is not what I'm looking for, sorry you can't continue <p><a href='?'>Lets try that again...</a>";
        }
    }


if(!isset($_SESSION['secured']))
{
    echo "<form method='post'>

    <form id='login' action='login.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login</legend>
            <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

            <label for='username' >UserName: </label>
            <input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName"  maxlength="50" required="true" />

            <label for='password' >Password:</label>
            <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" required="true"/>

            <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />    
        </fieldset>
    </form>
}
else
{
    ?>


<html>
    <head>
        <title>Session Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>You have been successfully logged in ... </p>
    </body>
</html>


<?php 
    }
?>
```

Comment: May I ask, what was your *certain* occupation while spending that "huge amount of time"? What did you do?

Comment: I am retired and have been for 7 years now.

Comment: If anyone is seriously and genuinely, happy to help me l would be greatfull.

Comment: Unless this is a copy/paste issue, you are missing a closing `";` after `</form>` and before `} else` in your php -> `</form> }else{` should be `</form>"; }else{`

Comment: Thanks, l can not locate which </form> you are referring to. Is it possible to edit my entry above?

Comment: It is the `</form>` inside (at the end of) your `if(!isset($_SESSION['secured'])){` block

Comment: @Sean l have just created one of those jsfiddle to show you that my html works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/New_to_Websites/5A4vS/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/New_to_Websites/5A4vS/5/

Comment: @Your Common Sence , are you able to help me?

Comment: Nice question. But for some reason you decided not to answer to mine.

Comment: I did answer your question, you asked me my occupation. I am retired, and why even would you want to know, if you mind me asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some syntax/issues in your php code section

- `name="UserName"` is not the same as `$_POST['username']` -> `UserName` != `username`
- unescaped double quotes `"` in `UserName` & `password` inputs -> `<input type="text" ...` should be `<input type=\"text\" ...` or `<input type='text' ...`
- you are missing a closing `";` after `</form>` and before `} else` in your php -> `</form> }else{` should be `</form>"; }else{`

try updated your php code to

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['UserName'])){ 

        if(($_POST['UserName'] == "admin") && ($_POST['password'] == "adminpass"))
        {
            $_SESSION['secured'] = "Secured";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Oops! Looks like the username and password is not what I'm looking for, sorry you can't continue <p><a href='?'>Lets try that again...</a>";
        }
    }


if(!isset($_SESSION['secured']))
{
    echo "<form method='post'>

    <form id='login' action='login.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login</legend>
            <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

            <label for='username' >UserName: </label>
            <input type='text' id='UserName' name='UserName'  maxlength='50' required='true' />

            <label for='password' >Password:</label>
            <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength='50' required='true'/>

            <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />    
        </fieldset>
    </form>";
}
else
{
    ?>


<html>
    <head>
        <title>Session Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>You have been successfully logged in ... </p>
    </body>
</html>


<?php 
    }
?>
```

Comment: When l type anything in either login box, incorrect or correct it leads to a blank page www.........../login.php

Comment: Try turning on php error reporting by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);` to the top of your php page, just after your opening `<?php` tag -> `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);`. This will tell you if you have any other errors / syntax issues.

Comment: Thanks, then l reupload this on my server?

Comment: Yes, add the error reporting functions, reupload, try your form again, and it should show any errors. Once you fix your code make sure to remove the error reporting functions.

Comment: I have tried that and l got to my www.domain/login.php and it is just a white blank page. Really don't know why

Comment: It is displaying a page, but completely white and blank. Otherwise it would say 'Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

Comment: Ok @Sean the html form works as intended. won't let you click submit until both forms full. All l need is for it to work with this php or a similar one that will display a short message below the box forms "incorrect" and if both user and password match to go to a <aref...> html page